# IPC between service and Layered Service Provider

Tags: winsock

There are a lot of methods to do IPC between a service and LSP(winsock hook DLL).
But which is the most effective one? Named pipe, COM server, Shared memory, etc.
Any clue or tip will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on what you are after ? Speed. If soo

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14740/Fast-IPC-Communication-Using-Shared-Memory-and-Int

Winsocks might be slower.

Comment: yes, i use shared memory as my final solution, and works fine so far, thanks.